# Can the Equity Premium Puzzle apply equally to bonds?

Tags: macroeconomics, finance, bonds, asset-pricing, capital-returns

Mehra and Prescott (JME, 1985) use the consumption-based asset price model to express the expected spread of equity returns over, e.g., a risk-free Treasury bond, as
\begin{equation*}     
\mathbb{E}_t[spread_{t+1}] = - \frac{ cov_t( m_{t+1}, R_{t+1})}{ \mathbb{E}_t[m_{t+1}] }
\end{equation*}
Where $m$ is the stochastic discount factor, $R$ is the treasury return, and $cov$ is covariance.

But there’s *also* a spread between corporate bonds and the risk-free treasury bond. Can one use this or a similar expression to explain bond spreads?

A caveat is maybe that for equities the spread reflects the superior return of equities (a good thing), whereas corporate bond spreads over the risk-free asset reflects the greater risk of corporate bonds (a bad thing?).

Another consideration is that bonds have a fixed return rate rather than equities which have a variable ex-post return.